# Navigation graph scoped ViewModel not get cleaned on menu navigation (Drawer) events

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using Navigation components and integrated DrawerLayout for side navigation menu.

I have the following structure of navigation xml config:

```
<navigation 
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/nav_apple">

   <navigation android:id="@+id/nav_apple">
      <fragment
          android:id="@+id/nav_apple_fragment"
          android:name="com.my.AppleFragment"
          tools:layout="...">

      ... other fragments and actions which share ViewModel ...

   </navigation>

   <navigation android:id="@+id/nav_orange">
      <fragment
          android:id="@+id/nav_orange_fragment"
          android:name="com.my.OrangeFragment"
          tools:layout="...">
   </navigation>

</navigation>
```

And menu xml like this:

```
<menu>
    <group>
        <item
            android:id="@id/nav_apple"/>
        <item
            android:id="@id/nav_orange" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

In activity I have code very similar to the one from android docs (https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui):

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
    topLevelDestinationIds = setOf(
        R.id.nav_apple,
        R.id.nav_orange
    ),
    drawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
)
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
binding.navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

In `AppleFragment` and other fragments of 'nav_apple' graph I'm using the following code to use navigation graph-scoped ViewModel:

```
private val model: MyViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.nav_apple)
```

It allows me sharing data and works perfectly, but when I use side menu (Drawer) and navigate to another destination and back - ViewModel data persists, which is undesirable.

According to the docs `Any ViewModel objects created in this way live until the associated NavHost and its ViewModelStore are cleared or until the navigation graph is popped from the back stack.` and I thought this navigation drawer events are the case, but looks like I'm missing something.

Comment: How have you hooked up your side menu? Please include your activity code.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Yes, please check my updated question

Comment: Is `nav_apple` the `startDestination` of your `mobile_navigation` graph?

Comment: @ianhanniballake, yes, I've updated the question. Sorry for confusion

Comment: @ianhanniballake I've just tried to replace `startDestination` of `mobile_navigation` from `nav_apple` to `nav_orange` and it fixed the behavior - `nav_apple` model gets cleared, so looks I'm missing some special meaning of `startDestination` in this context. Unfortunately replacing start destination is not allowed by business logic, I'll need another way to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#fixed_start_destination), the start destination (and, if that `startDestination` points to a `<navigation>` graph, its `startDestination`) of your graph is always on the back stack.

As the navigation graph itself remains on the back stack, the state and ViewModels attached to that navigation graph also remains.

With the upcoming work on [multiple back stacks](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80029773), every bottom navigation item will have its own back stack and swapping between items will automatically save the current stack and restore it back when you reselect it. Therefore you should expect your bottom navigation items to automatically keep their ViewModels once that it is released.