# ViewModel with SavedStateHandle scoped to navigation destination

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, android-jetpack-navigation, android-mvvm

I have a ViewModel that takes arguments (e.g. person profile screen that takes the id of the person to display as an argument). This is used within a fragment that is part of a navigation graph.

If I use:

```
val viewModel: PersonDetailViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.mobile_navigation) {
        provideFactory(di, requireParentFragment(), requireArguments())
}
...

companion object { 
   fun provideFactory(
            di: DI,
            owner: SavedStateRegistryOwner,
            defaultArgs: Bundle? = null,
        ): AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory = object: AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory(owner, defaultArgs) {
            override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(
                key: String,
                modelClass: Class<T>,
                handle: SavedStateHandle
            ): T {
                return PersonDetailViewModel(di, SavedStateHandleAdapter(handle)) as T
            }
        }
}
```

The ViewModel will not be disposed of, even when the user leaves the destination and it is popped off the stack. When the user goes to the same destination with different arguments, we get the old view model.

As per [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#share_ui-related_data_between_destinations_with_viewmodel) "Any ViewModel objects created in this way live until the associated NavHost and its ViewModelStore are cleared or until the navigation graph is popped from the back stack.". I get the same problem even when I replace requireParentFragment() with findNavController().currentBackStackEntry

I want to scope the ViewModel to the back stack entry so that:

1. Whenever the user goes to a new screen with new arguments, a new ViewModel gets created
2. Whenever the destination fragment is popped from the backstack, the ViewModel is disposed of and resources are released.

If I use:

```
val viewModel: PersonDetailViewModel by viewModels(ownerProducer = { this } ) {
            provideFactory(di, findNavController().currentBackStackEntry ?: throw IllegalStateException("no backstackentry!"), requireArguments())
        }
```

This seems to do roughly what I want. It creates a new ViewModel for new arguments on the new destination. The ViewModel is kept as long as this destination remains on the backstack (and cleared as soon as it is popped). If the process is destroyed and the user returns, the SavedStateHandle data is available as expected.

Is there a better way to do things? I have read this post about [viewmodels not being cleaned up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67257373/navigation-graph-scoped-viewmodel-not-get-cleaned-on-menu-navigation-drawer-ev), but it doesn't address how to scope to a back stack entry (top level or not).